# How to use the excelweb-addin?

Tags: excel

How to achieve excel web external page jump, such as having a home.html in the solution, and then click a login button, jump to welcome.html, and can not leave the right box in the container.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g6eYI.png)
and [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/87TvU.png)

excelwebaddin internal page how to jump, etc.